# Generate a custom map icon (lightning-map)

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I'm working on a project where I need to dynamically add text to the map icon used within a map visualization. The `lightning-map` documentation does not support a text property directly within the custom icon configuration. What is a workaround or alternative method to include dynamic text within my custom icon?